# 2nd floor bath remodel. Concrete under tile. What do I have to remove?

Tags: bathroom, tile, subfloor

I am doing some preliminary research and investigation into remodeling my master bath.

The house was built in 2002 so not too old. The master bath is on second floor. I removed the air vent to see what I am dealing with under the tile and it appears to be some sort of metal mesh stapled to either a wood sub-floor or the joists with concrete on top of it, about 3/4" thick and then the tile.

I am going down to studs in this bathroom, but I'm unsure of the floor.

Can I remove the tile and thinset and just re-tile on the concrete 'sub-floor'?
**Or** will I likely need to remove the concrete too? (*I would think that's overkill*).

If removing the concrete is necessary, what replaces it?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Your second  level floor is a concrete floor?

Comment: No I don't think so.  I just think they used a concrete underlayment on top of the wood subfloor for the tile job.

Comment: Do tiles continue up the wall? I ask because there is a high likelihood that the cement and wire continue up the wall if so.

Comment: There is one row of tile “trim” up the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a standard old school "float" job: plywood, then (usually) tar paper, then expanded metal mesh (sometimes), then dry-pack concrete, then tile adhered with thin-set mortar. This was the standard way to get a strong flat substrate for tile before cement-board was common.

**If** you can get the tiles off with the cement still relatively flat and smooth (or if the cement can be *made* relatively flat and smooth) then it is perfectly fine to put new tile down on it... but it's a **big** if.

Comment: That's sort of fascinating.  I didn't realize cement board was "relatively" new.  I used it in a bathroom re-model about 10 years ago and thought it'd been around for 20 years before that

Comment: It takes time before the crafts tradesmen accept new techniques and products; they tend to stick to "the way we've always done it". I know tile guys who still want to float floors; it **is** (arguably) better in some ways and for some situations.

Comment: @SteveSether, I started out "humping mud" in 5-gal buckets back in the early '80s, then was "promoted" to grouting... back then we 'floated" everything, no cement board in sight.